# OpenLayers - Detect Switch between full screen, regular screen

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have been searching but have not come to an answer.

Is there a way to detect the event which OpenLayers enters FullScreen/exits FullScreen?  In short, i need to toggle classes of some divs.  I tried adding events to the buttons, but then it doesn't work if they press escape instead.

Thanks.

Comment: No OL3 native way. See https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this what OL uses? @jonatas-walker

Comment: Never mind, I think I got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The comment suggesting using 'screenfull' is a good option for now. screenfull is just a wrapper that smooths out the cross browser implementation issues of the fairly new ['Fullscreen API'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API). Until the browsers have fully implemented the standards for these events, that little wrapper is a good way forward.

If you are just wanting to style things differently, there is a CSS pseudo selector for that - `:fullscreen`. No JavaScript required! You can [read the documentation for it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) and there is [also a great example](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen$samples/Example?revision=1093433). Take special note of the need for the vendor prefixes and the fact that some browsers say `full-screen` rather than the standard `fullscreen`. The various mix of selectors you'll need seem to currently be:

`:-moz-full-screen` - Gecko based browsers

`:-ms-fullscreen` - IE/Edge

`:-webkit-full-screen` - WebKit based browsers

`:fullscreen` - Standards compliant browsers